# Google sheets - cross join / cartesian join from two separate columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, cartesian-product, cross-join

Hope that someone can help me with a cartesian product in Google Sheets. I have data in two separate columns and wish to create all possible combinations of the two columns in a separate tab. The first column is ID (text) and the second is date format. The output should be two separate columns. The formula should be dynamic, i.e. list should update when new IDs or dates are added to the input lists.

I have looked for solutions online, but haven't found a solution that works. I'm proficient in Excel but not so much Google Sheet :)

Here is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/150uIg3XH1hxZa8vSxDhcVZVOcSEOp175OPYL4Rc-wWI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SPLIT(
    FLATTEN(
        FILTER('input 1'!A2:A, 'input 1'!A2:A <> "")
      & ","
      & TRANSPOSE(FILTER('input 2'!A2:A, 'input 2'!A2:A <> ""))
    ),
    ","
  )
)
```

in cell `A3` but make sure you reformat column B into `date` (copy the format from column E):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. 

Currently there are 10 IDs ('input'!A2:A11) and 12 months ('input 2'!A2:A13). Do you know if it is possible to make the formula "dynamic", so that if I add a new ID, the formula will automatically detect and change to "'input'!A2:A12"?

Thanks!

Comment: @WilliamPontoppidan fixed formula a bit with `FILTER` to support open ranges, to make it dynamic.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much! @WilliamPontoppidan You haven't marked any as an answer by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I think soMarios's solution is better in your case, but here is another solution just to show a different approach. With some work this approach could be generalized for any number of columns.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  {
    VLOOKUP(
      INT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA('input 1'!A2:A) * COUNTA('input 2'!A2:A), 1,) / COUNTA('input 2'!A2:A)) + 1,
      {SEQUENCE(COUNTA('input 1'!A2:A)), FILTER('input 1'!A2:A, 'input 1'!A2:A <> "")},
      2,
    ),
    VLOOKUP(
      MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA('input 1'!A2:A) * COUNTA('input 2'!A2:A), 1,), COUNTA('input 2'!A2:A)) + 1,
      {SEQUENCE(COUNTA('input 2'!A2:A)), FILTER('input 2'!A2:A, 'input 2'!A2:A <> "")},
      2,
    )
  }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `LAMBDA` you could also use this without relying on string hacking:

```
=LAMBDA(
  range_1, range_2, count_1, count_2,
  {
    BYROW(
      INDEX(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(count_1 * count_2) / count_2)),
      LAMBDA(r, INDEX(range_1, r))
    ),
    BYROW
      (INDEX(MOD(SEQUENCE(count_1 * count_2) - 1, count_2) + 1),
      LAMBDA(r, INDEX(range_2, r))
    )
  }
)('input 1'!A2:A, 'input 2'!A2:A, COUNTA('input 1'!A2:A), COUNTA('input 2'!A2:A))
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 OFFSET('input 1'!A2,,,COUNTA('input 1'!A2:A))&"♠"&TRANSPOSE(
 OFFSET('input 2'!A2,,,COUNTA('input 2'!A2:A)))), "♠"))
```

[image]

and format B column as date

Comment: A solution without an explanation is not much of a solution.  There is a strange character in  play on your answer.  I suspect it is part of your strategy, but the strategy is completely missing in this answer.

Comment: @barrypicker happy to explain it to you if you need so. here is some introduction to cartesian product: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125018/186471